# Структура БД много к много

Tags: sql, алгоритм, структуры

Для упрощения понимания: есть таблица с пользователями одной соц. сети.
Парсер дополняет таблицу друзьями уже имеющихся в базе пользователями.

Помогите составить структуру базу данных, так чтобы пользователей оставить в одной таблице. И при этом выгружать при необходимости взаимосвязи между участниками.

В этом вопросе мне не хватает теории, практика отточена.
Буду благодарен за любой полезный комментарий.

Comment: может для начала литературу почитать?

Comment: вы составьте, а мы подскажем правильно или нет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude пока только таблица users и csv-файл со списком друзей (формируется питоном), 
по литературе: читаю про соц.сети,  и высокие нагрузки ( потому как уже собрал больше 20 млн строк)

Comment: Да не соцсети надо читать, а основы проектирования баз данных...

Comment: @Akina вот  на этом этапе  запутался: для много к много рекомендуют две таблицы исходных данных и ещё одну таблицу связей между ними. В моём случае это нецелесообразно. Две таблицы пользователей - глупо

Comment: Читал много, но основное пропустил... Две таблицы исходных данных - это если связываются две сущности. А у тебя она одна, просто экземпляров два - так и таблица тоже одна.

Comment: @Akina получается что будет таблица users и таблица friends в которой будут указанные связи. А поиск будет по двум стобцам одновременно. если так - то спасибо, разобрался в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без оглядки на синтаксис:

```
Create Table Users (id, name);
Create table Relations ( id1 references Users(id)
                       , id2 references Users(id)
                       , primary key (id1, id2)
                       , check constraint id1 < id2
                       );
```

Дружба предполагается симметричной. Для несимметричной constraint удалить.

Схема имеет свои плюсы и свои минусы. Последних тоже немало.

Comment: попробуем реализовать